# Как задать DataContext для ListBoxItem внутри UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

Создал `UserControl` с `ListBox` внутри:

```
 <catel:UserControl 
            x:Class="WPFApplication2.Views.UserView"                   
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:catel="http://schemas.catelproject.com"
           xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">

<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Width="500" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Labels}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Label Height="{Binding Path=Height}"
                               Width="{Binding Path=Width}"
                               Content="{Binding Path=Content}">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand , 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=catel:UserControl}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </Label>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>

</catel:UserControl>
```

Чтоб не делал не работает свойство `Command` в `Label` при том если поместить `Label` вне `ListBox` или заменить `UserControl` на `Window` всё работает отлично!

Пробовал указывать `DataContext` и через `FindAncestor` и через указания `ElementName` на `UserControl` - ничего не помогло, при этом не работает только `Command` остальные свойства привязываются без проблем.Работаю в Catel.

Comment: А если `AncestorType` указать как `ListBox`?

Comment: Спасибо помогло) Всё так просто, а я 2 дня мучился...

Comment: Можно еще попробовать добавить имя `<catel:UserControl ... Name="myControl" ...` и потом привязываться через `ElementName=myControl`, будет чуть короче код привязки

Comment: я так пробовал - работать не будет, всё же просто до `ListBox` проивязывать `DataContext` надо, а способ уже не столь важен.